# Chrome process shows up in Windows Task Manager, but not Chrome Task Manager

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome

Windows 7, 64-bit.

When I start Chrome, and open the in-browser Task Manager, I see one less process reported than I see in Windows' Task Manager.  This extra process starts and stops with the rest of Chrome, and generally uses ~1MB of memory.

[image]

Notice that PID 3700 does not show up on Chrome's list.  Is this expected?

Comment: Still an issue. Noticed it today when looking at Chrome child processes that were using too much CPU according to Windows TM (overall around 3 processes using ~35% CPU on an i7 8th gen). Went to `Details` for each and noted the PID. Guess what, they don't show in the internal task manager. Killed them manually and haven't noticed crashes, issues or otherwise. Makes me very worried if this had been a webpage somehow exploiting me, though. But what could you invoke from javascript that spawns hidden browser processes?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome also has a background process that runs in Windows. So yes, you may not see every process in the Chrome Task Manager that you do in the Windows Task Manager